# Is there a Mule idiom that sends a JMS message without overwriting the payload that should be returned?

Tags: mule

I'd like to send a JMS message at the beginning and end of processing a REST request. I can do something like this:

```
<set-variable variableName="savedPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Variable" />
<scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
    <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
        <scripting:text><![CDATA[
            '{"event" : "TRY"}'
        ]]></scripting:text>
    </scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
<jms:outbound-endpoint queue="event.detail" connector-ref="jmsConnector" />
<expression-transformer evaluator="groovy" expression="savedPayload" />
```

Essentially, the JMS would just be used to record the entry and exit (SUCCESS or FAILED) while preserving the saved message, which the code above does using a variable. What's a shorter, idiomatic way of doing this in a Mule flow?

Edit:

To put this another way, is there a way to send that outbound message with a payload without the save/restore needed to hang on to the response payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Async` scope. It will execute asynchronously your message processors in a different branch and you won't have to worry about saving/restoring the payload.

```
<async>
    <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
      <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
        <scripting:text><![CDATA[
            '{"event" : "TRY"}'
        ]]></scripting:text>
      </scripting:script>
   </scripting:component>
  <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="event.detail" connector-ref="jmsConnector" />
</async>
```

more details about async scope: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Async+Scope+Reference

Comment: Yeah, that's the ticket. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Wire Tap router. This way you can pass you paylaod to another channel where you can modify or outbound it without distrubing your main cahnnel.  [Mule Routers Guide](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/MULE2USER/Inbound+Routers)

Answer (score 0):

The best option will be **message enricher** :-
https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Message+Enricher
Message enricher component doesn't disturb the existing payload and you can set anything inside it... it will not affect the payload